# Fetching arrays of different length from an API

Tags: javascript

I created a website with data from Countries API, but it is incomplete because I only fetched one official language of each country and obviously there are countries with more official languages. Their API gives this for Canada for example:

```
languages: Array(2)
0:
iso639_1: "en"
iso639_2: "eng"
name: "English"
nativeName: "English"
__proto__: Object
1:
iso639_1: "fr"
iso639_2: "fra"
name: "French"
nativeName: "français"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I used this code to get language:

```
<h3 class='languages'>Languages: ${country.languages[0].name}</h3>
```

but if I add ${country.languages[1].name} code obviously fails because not all countries have second item in languages array. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `map` over the countries and potentially `join` them with a comma if there are multiple.

```
<h3 class='languages'>
  Languages: ${country.languages.map(el => el.name).join(', ')}
</h3>
```

A couple examples of this in action:

```js
const languages1 = [{ name: "English" }, { name: "French" }];
const languages2 = [{ name: "German" }];

console.log(languages1.map(el => el.name).join(", "));
console.log(languages2.map(el => el.name).join(", "));
```